# Javascript self hide parent div not hiding when span clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that's been created dynamically. Multiple of them are created and I need to do a self parent hide, so this is what I've done:

This Div:

```
<div><a href="">'+inputText+'-</a><div class="box"></div><span onclick="dismiss();">Close</span></div>
```

The Function:

```
function dismiss() {
    $(this).parents('div').fadeOut();
}
```

It's not hidding when I click the close span.

Comment: just a thought if you hide everything problem on showing will occur. it's just a thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `dismiss` function `this` refers to window object, instead pass the `this` as an argument .

```js
function dismiss(ele) {
  $(ele).parents('div').fadeOut();
  console.log(this);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="">'+inputText+'-</a>
  <div class="box"></div><span onclick="dismiss.bind(this);dismiss(this);">Close</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not access `$(this)` directly into any function:

So:
pass this as parameter:

```
<span onclick="dismiss(this);">Close</span>

function dismiss(obj) {
    $(obj).parents('div').fadeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a span for this, consider using a button. It would be semantically appropriate. Maybe even change the <div> to a <p> (depending on if it is a paragraph or not). Keep in mind that you can't have a div inside a p though, so you would need to change the .box div to a span.

```
<div>
    <a href="">'+inputText+'-</a>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <button onclick="dismiss(this);">Close</button>
</div>
```

And for the JS:

```
function dismiss(obj) {
$(obj).parents('div').fadeOut();
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, change the html

```
<div>
  <a href="">Click</a>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <span id="btn">Close</span>
</div>
```

And JS

```
$(document).on('click','#btn', function(){
  $(this).parents('div').hide();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8t4d6xs/)